# Earliest to do kapporos

Tags: calendar, kaparot

What is the earliest date that you can do Kapporos? Is it rosh hashanah?

(Note: I'm not asking for the best or most preferable time.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes and no

Mishna berrura 605.2

> ...
>
> כי כל עשי"ת הוא זמן לכפרות [פמ"ג ע"ש].
>
> ...

My translation

> All of the 10 days of teshuva is the time for kappros [pri megodim, see there]

but

from the maharal m'prag's book

נתיבות עולם - נתיב הבטחון - פרק א

[page 232 last paragraph on the page](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14205&pgnum=234) and the first paragraph [on the next page](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14205&pgnum=235)

it seems that anytime during the year when you lose a chicken (even when it is not shechted) it is a kaporo of your neshomo

P.S. but from other places i saw it seems to me that it is kaporos only when it shechted correctly (maybe i am wrong)

Comment: The first part answers the question, in the second part, the maharal says that from this story there's proof that you need to do Kapporos on erev yom Kippur (which I know is the best time to do it)

Comment: It's interesting, because it didn't say that that story happened on erev yom Kippur, unless he means that based on his explanation, so on erev yom Kippur, when you need a kapparah, you should definitely need to do it

Comment: @user613 I understand the maaral mprag that the minhag it to do it on erev yom kippur (as the ramo sais in shulchan aruch) to make a kaporo for our neshama before yom Kippur (probably it will help on yom Kippur) but the story is a prove (asmachta) that the lose of a chicken is a kaporo for the neshama (anytime during the year)

Comment: ומזה ראיה גמורה מן הגמרא ליקח תרגגול לכפרה על נפשו בערב יום הכופורים ודבר זה ידוע I fail to see how that means all year round

Comment: I ticked your answer because the first part answers it, nothing got to do with the 2nd part.

Comment: @user613 Your quote does not, but before when he wrote about the weasel came and ate the rooster it was a kaporo for the neshomo of rabi akiva, I understood it that whenever your chicken gets killed it is a kaporo (tmura)

Comment: I agrees that it would seem that way from the story, except that that's not what the maharal said. I want to check this up further when I have time